# Tweepy mentions_timeline returns an empty list

Tags: python, python-3.4, tweepy, tweets, mention

I just started to make a Twitter Api. Normally I don't have a Twitter account, for this api I created one. I Tweeted 4 times, including some mentions. But when I use `mentions_timeline` like this;

```
my_mentions = api.mentions_timeline()
#print(my_mentions)
#output: []
```

After then I do a for loop on my_mentions with parameters `text`, `screen_name` but nothing returned.

What I'm doing wrong here? Why it's an empty list since I mentioned some people in the tweets + how can I search mentions for another user? Is there a parameter in `mentions_timeline()` object like `screen_name` or `id` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the new [Cursor Object](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/cursor_tutorial.html) as follows:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for mentions in tweepy.Cursor(api.mentions_timeline).items():
    # process mentions here
    print mentions.text
```

as per Twitters documentation [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/mentions_timeline)

> Returns the 20 most recent mentions (tweets containing a users’s
>   @screen_name) for the authenticating user.

so you cannot check other users mentions using this method. To achieve this, you will have to uses twitters [search api.](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search) for tweepy's documentation check [here](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html)

Comment: still nothing returned

Comment: you have to "tweet" something with your twitter username and mention yourself in the tweet

Comment: or have someone else mention you in the tweet

Comment: I did. Actually I put screen_name into mentions_timeline and an error raised: tweepy.error.RateLimitError: [{'code': 88, 'message': 'Rate limit exceeded'}]

Comment: I only have 4 tweets and 2 of them mentioned someone

Comment: what i am saying is, you have to mention yourself in the tweet, if you mention someone else, it wont appesr in the results, and you dont have to add yourself in the mentions_timeline as a parameter

Comment: For Ex. tweet  @GLHF hello to myself, and that is what the mentions_timeline method will return

Comment: Really? that is absurd. What if I want to find mentioned tweets of a user and that user not mention himself? I don't think people mention theirselves first, before mention someone else?

Comment: for that you have to use the search API, not the mentions method, it is specified in twitters documentation

Comment: Well then this method is really absurd, I don't used twitter before but a method that finds 'mention yourself' is really weird. Thanks for your answer anyways, I'll check search API.

Comment: the mentions_timeline is in the statuses/mentions_timeline rest api

Comment: no  prob, the point of the mentions_timeline, is to check messages that other ppl have mentioned you in

Comment: Well, I just used api.search("veysel") and here is the error:UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 173633-173633: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk

Answer (score 0):

import tweepy

api = tweepy.API(auth)

api.mentions_timeline()

Comment: Please format your code properly. Also, consider adding few lines describing your solution.

Comment: Your answer does not solve the problem. Beyond solving the problem, format your code and explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your profile using the same of which you're using the API and see whether the mentions exists in your profile.
and try mentioning the twitter account from different account which you trying from.
This might be the case where twitter had limited your activities and replies/tweets are not visible of that account.